# JavaScript, HTML, no JQuery - how to add a string that contains a link in the middle of a sentence?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, hyperlink, href

I am fairly new to JavaScript.
I'm trying to add a paragraph to a HTML (preferably using DOM). A paragraph should contain a string, a sentence, that has a link in the middle.
A paragraph will have different contents depending on a user choice and will display on a webpage after clicking a button. Part of my code that is related to the question pasted below. Where a link will be 'contactThem'.

```js
//Returns a correct text to be displayed in a hidden panel.
function displayText(result) {
    const fR = parseInt(result);
    const contactThem = "<a href='form.html'>form</a>";
    let toInclude = "";
    if (fR < 5) {
        toInclude = "Some text";
    } else {
        toInclude = "Different text" + contactThem + "more text.";
    }
    return toInclude;
}

//Displays hidden panel with contents
function showPanel(displayText) {
    const toShow = displayText;
    const square = document.getElementById("toBeDisplayed");
    while (square.hasChildNodes()) {
        square.removeChild(square.lastChild);
    }
    const yourM = document.createElement("h2");
    let yourMT = document.createTextNode("Title");
    const pp = document.createElement("p");
    let ppT = document.createTextNode(toShow);
    yourM.appendChild(yourMT);
    square.appendChild(yourM);
    pp.appendChild(ppT);
    square.appendChild(pp);
    square.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

I suspect that my approach might be wrong... 
I was thinking about maybe creating 2 separate divs and displaying them depending on users choice, but I really would rather do it in JavaScript if possible.
I do understand that adding links as variables is incorrect. It is a temporary holder until I have a solution.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. You're also never calling `displayText` in your code. Can you clarify what the precise issue is?

Comment: apologies, I edited my post and added displayText call.

Comment: There's still no `displayText` call. I assume you mean to use something like `pp.innerHTML = displayText(5);`

Comment: so sorry, I'm such an idiot and new to all this :( Hopefully my last edit corrected the issue.

Comment: There's still no call. What you have is `function showPanel(displayText)` which means you can now access the first parameter passed to a `showPanel(...)` call by `displayText`. This will actually prevent you from being able to call the `displayText` function you have, since that local variable now shadows the function. And a text node shouldn't include HTML.  https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/nvpaLy0f/

Comment: hmm I think all this problems with calling functions came from the fact that those are just 2 functions out of many. I have a separate main() function which triggers all the others. I only pasted in 2 functions with which I had trouble. In my code the parameters I use are: function displayResult(result, factors). In my main function I call it:
 var factors = factorsFactors(choices);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you want to add an HTML Element, such as `<a href="http://my_url.com">` inside an existing element, you can do so with `HTMLElement.innerHTML = "text that will be rendered"` (as opposed to `HTMLElement.innerText`, which will render everything as is).

In your case, it would be something like:

```
const contactThem = "<a href='form.html'>form</a>";
let el = document.createElement("p")
el.innerHTML = "Different text" + contactThem + "other text."
```

Comment: pierre thank you so much, it is a perfect solution for me and so simple. *edit: typo